# Natural Language Processing using apache OpenNLP

Tags: nlp

How do I find the accuracy of a data in % in Natural Language Processing?

Trying to find accuracy on movie review data

Once the fresh movie review comes, to decide whether the review is positive or not, process followed as below

For training purpose used movie review file of size 400 MB which has 200 K + review comments and its corresponding ratings.

Based on the ratings in the file implemented the bag of words approach
for e.g.: if rating > 5 then put it into the good bag else bad bag

While implementing bag of words approach used below NLP techniques

1. Tokenization
2. Stop word Removal
3. Stemming
4. Special character removal etc

Once the bag is ready, with fresh review comments using NLP techniques as stated above then looking up in the bags calculating mean on good and bad bags whichever is greater based on that deciding whether the fresh review is positive or not.

Please suggest how to figure out the accuracy in %?

Answer (score 0):

Split your data into train ans test set. Then, you can evaluate (calculate the accuracy in %) your model trained on your training set on your test. To achieve more reliable results, you can evaluate your method in cross-fold evaluation manner.